# scilabs: How do I print the current values in %ODEOPTIONS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning scilabs(6.0.0)  and trying to understand some basic features related to ode.

How do I print the current values in %ODEOPTIONS. I tried but it says undefined variable as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Kindly enlighten me since I am very new to SCILABS

When we type %pi on command, it prints 3.14..., so why not %ODEOPTIONS correctly printing?

Comment: I have checked doc. My point is %ODEOPTIONS when given on prompt should print default values. But it says undefined variable

Comment: when we type %pi on command, it prints 3.14..., so why not %ODEOPTIONS correctly printing?